# User roles data structure

Tags: sql

This is my STRUCTURE for User role permissions

```
    permissions
    id
    name = The name of the __ACTION__ like, "UpdateNews" or something like that

roles
id
name = Guest/Admin/etc.

role_permissions //connect the roles with permissions
role_id 
permission_id
```

The idea is that I do something like this:

```
$user->hasPermission('updateNews') !== false
// do stuff
```

Now, this requires me to give users all permissions, that is required, the thing is, Let's say I have a role called "administrator", and I would like to give him all permissions, in a quick way, instead of adding all rows, how can the easiest and best way do this? And while we are on it, are my user role approach good?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, for administrator you could have a class/method that can override this hasPermission method. And for this approach, instead of checking by your own code before every invocation, try to use some technique like aspect-oriented programming.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5734277

(note:article might be a little bit overkill)